# How to send amp-state when submitting the form from amp email?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="url_goes_here">
        <input hidden name="foo" value="bar" [value]="details">
</form>
```

I want to send states in amp-email form, I have a hidden input 
This **details** is a dict with all the data stored in the states that I want.

This is what I get on the backend from the request

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('foo', 'bar')])
```

Comment: Parsed the ImmutableMultiDict thing but just the problem now is that, i'm not being able  states to the request

Comment: As I understand it, your problem is that amp-bind is not initiated immediately after opening the email. Therefore, no data is written to input: [value]="details".

I see two possible solutions:
1).So that before the form appears in the email, the user clicks somewhere(then we will update amp-bind). For example, the form will be hidden by default, and to open it, the user must click on the button.

Comment: 2). Try wrapping the form in amp-list. Then amp-bind will be initiated immediately. But then there may be a problem with amp-mustache. The solution is possible here: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-mustache/?format=email#pitfalls

Comment: Post your working code. Take the basic template here: https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/ and make a working example.